# search a databse by using a cfquery inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coldfusion

Hi this is my first question on stackoverflow :) 
trying to get coldfusion working with javascript.

I'm trying to pull out data off a database and show it in my page.
but i realized js is a client side language and cf being serverside.
I can't just run cfquery inside a function so i have two files

one is my index.html

```
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body class="jumbotron">
<div class="container text-center " >

        <div class="row">
            <img class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4" src="emp.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px" >
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <div id="imaginary_container"> 

                <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchBar" name="searchBar" placeholder="Search" >
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <button onclick="search(global,$http)">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>                          

                    </span>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<script> 
function search($scope, $http) {
    var searchQ = document.getElementById('searchBar').value;

    $http.get('/grid.cfc?method=getContact&returnformat=json').
        success(function (response) {
            $scope.todos = data.DATA;
    }).
        error(function (data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
        });
};    



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and one is my grid.cfc

```
    <cfcomponent>

<cffunction name="getContact" access="remote" >
    <cfargument name="firstName" default="">
    <cfargument name="lastName" default="">

    <cfquery name="searchQry" datasource="MehrabanDSource">
        SELECT
            *
        FROM Contacts
        WHERE FirstName=fname;

    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn searchQry>
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

can you help me make sense of my code, i don't really know if im on the right track or how can i pass in a variable to my grid.cfm so it knows what first name to look for. THANKS A LOT in ADVANCE :)

Comment: You are making a large number of mistakes.  I suggest starting again from scratch.  Take baby steps such as, get your query to work not using CF, get your query to work using CF, getting it to work inside a function, and so on and so forth.  Once you have successfully achieved something, don't change it.

Comment: Are you being forced to use ColdFusion? Why are you using it?

Comment: I agree with Dan's comments. Start simply. Write code to do one thing. Test it. Lather, rinse, repeat. Also, this statement jumped out at me: *i have two files ... one is my **grid.CFM***. Components must be stored in a `.cfc` file. If you store them in a `.cfm` script, they will not work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

thank you Dan, thank you Leigh :) i used :

```
  <cfajaxproxy cfc="functions" jsclassname="ajax_proxy" /> 
  <cfajaximport> 
  <script> 
         function send_ajax(searchBar) {
           var instance = new ajax_proxy(); 
           instance.setCallbackHandler(return_ajax); 
           instance.functionality(searchBar); 
          } 
           function return_ajax(result) { 
                   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;
           }
   </script>
```

Comment: Glad you got something working. However, personally I would recommend sticking with your original approach. CF has a lot of good features, but .. the ajax stuff is not one of them ;-) It is uses outdated js libraries and is notoriously clunky IMO. It would not take much to get your original example working. I suspect the biggest problem was using a .cfm file instead of .cfc. (Side note, not sure what your final `cfquery` looks like, but be sure to use `cfqueryparam` ie bind variables to protect your db against sql injections).